# Displaying custom error message for a blank field in a simple JSF application

Tags: jsf, message

I was trying out a simple JSF application, in which I need to check if the "name" field is blank, then display an error message.

The code which takes the field's value is:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Name"/>
<h:inputText value="#{greeting.name}" required="true">
    <f:validator validatorId="NumValidator"/>
</h:inputText>
```

The control of the program does not go into the validator class, if the field is submitted without entering anything, and it displays the default error message:

**j_id_jsp_869892673_1:j_id_jsp_869892673_4: Validation Error: Value is required.**

How do i display a custom message for this ?

Comment: Note that when you **actually** would like to override that ugly-looking `j_id_jsp_869892673_1:j_id_jsp_869892673_4`, then you need to specify the `label` attribute of the `UIInput` element, e.g. `<h:inputText label="Name">`.

Comment: @BalusC: thanks. wanted to get rid of that ugly j_id_jsp_869892673_1:j_id_jsp_869892673_4

Comment: with PrimeFaces there is attribute `requiredMessage`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `Message.properties` file stored the default validation messages. This file is contained in the JAR of the JSF implementation library.

If you look at the content of this file, regarding the *required* validation, you will see that:

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED={0}: Validation Error: Value is required.
```

To define your own error messages, create a new properties file, add the adequate error message, for example:

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED=Hey, you forgot to fill the input {0}!
```

(note that `{0}` will be replaced by the ID of the field)

then, in your `faces-config.xml`, define a new `message-bundle`:

```
<message-bundle>package.that.contains.the.properties.file</message-bundle>
```

So for example, if your `my-messages.properties` is stored in the foo/bar package, you will have to write:

```
<application>
  ...
  <message-bundle>foo.bar.my-messages</message-bundle>
</application>
```

(note that you will not have to specify the `.properties` extension)

Answer (score 2):

The way suggested by **romaintaz** is definitely way to go.
On the other hand if you are looking for more customization, you can use a **phase listene**r that fires before render response phase as does some customizing.

For example first define the value for key as below:

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED=INPUT_REQ_FAIL
```

then for input components that require validation have them pass a attribute using f:attribute .Then in phase listener iterate over the face messages and check for INPUT_REQ_FAIL and replace it with cutom message along with the attribute value for the component.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should look at JSR 303! This is fully standard based user input, it works out of the box with JSF 2 (I use My Faces). And the nice thing is, no need for xml or properties files to specify custom messages.